# Stream and create a list of JSON objects

Tags: java, json, serialization

I am stuck with the following issue. I have a string that I want to encode as a JSON (discarding some of the information it carries). The string is the following:

```
{
"success": true,
"cli": [
    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SNMP" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SNMP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "group" }, { "token": "Ping" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "group" }, { "token": "Ping" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SSH Management" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "2" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SSH Management" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTPS Management" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "3" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTPS Management" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTP Management" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "4" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTP Management" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "group" }, { "token": "Ping" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "5" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "group" }, { "token": "Ping" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SSH Management" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "6" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SSH Management" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTPS Management" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "7" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTPS Management" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTP Management" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "8" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "LAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "HTTP Management" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "any" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "source" }, { "token": "group" }, { "token": "All Interface IP" }, { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "9" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "group" }, { "token": "All Interface IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Auto-added X1 Default NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },

    { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "10" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Auto-added X0 outbound NAT Policy for X1 WAN" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] },


    { "command": [ { "token": "end" } ] }
] }
```

This string is a response from a Sonicwall router and lists all the saved NAT policies. What I am doing is using this part of code to stream (I am using the JSON Processing library), remove the unwanted information and create a new JSON object out of the above.

```
byte[] jsonExampleByte = jsonExample.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonExampleByte);
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    JsonObject myJson = null;

    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(stream);
    JsonObject jObject = reader.readObject();

    System.out.println("JSON Object: " + jObject.toString());

    JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(null);

    myJson = factory.createObjectBuilder().add("success", jObject.get("success")).add("cli", factory.createArrayBuilder().add(factory.createObjectBuilder().add("submode", jObject.getJsonArray("cli").getJsonObject(1).get("submode")))).build();

    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("my_new_json");
    JsonWriter wr = Json.createWriter(fs);
    wr.writeObject(myJson);
    wr.close();
```

The problem that I have is that even though the above code works nicely. I am able to create only one new JSON object (containing the first one). What I want to do is to create a bunch of new objects from the input stream and store them in a list. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I don't know this Json processing library, but the `JsonReader` should have a method to read an array or list of `JsonObject`s. Once you have that array, just iterate over it and create an array of your own `JsonObject`s. Then, just use the `JsonWriter` to write your array.

Comment: If i try to do that, I get the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" javax.json.JsonException: Cannot read JSON array, found JSON object
 at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readArray(JsonReaderImpl.java:122)
 at JsonTest.main(JsonTest.java:36)